# Sails.js session not saved upon first request

Tags: session, redis, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js and trying to do a simple login with saving the user information to the session. Here's my code for the login action:

```
AuthService.login(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(user => {

    // save user information in the session
    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.authenticated = true;

    return res.json({
      user:user,
      token:token
    });
}).catch(err => {
  sails.log.error(err);
  res.json(403, {
    callstack: err.callstack,
    error: 'Authentication error',
    reason : err.reason
  });
});
```

This is my policy for the other pages (after login):

```
  module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  // User is allowed, proceed to the next policy,
  if (req.session.authenticated && req.session.user) {
      return next();
  }

  // User is not allowed
  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action. (Authenticated)');
  };
```

**The problem** is that the session data is not saved for the first request meaning I'm getting 403 forbidden *only* after the first successful login. As a result I must then logout and then login again for the session data to appear.

The issue is *not* limited to the login (with authentication policy) but also applies for any action that requires the session data with or without policy. And occurs for each new session - not only the first time the server goes up.

---

I thought the problem was due to using memory session so I've also tried to configure Sail.js to work with Redis as the session store by modifying the config/session.js to the following:

```
  adapter: 'redis',

  // host: 'localhost',
  // port: 6379,
  // ttl: 60*60*20,
  // db: 0,
  // prefix: 'sess:',
```

I uncommented the adapter line and tried with and without the optional redis connection parameters but then the req.session was declared undefined everywhere

Comment: Not sure what is happening, I never experienced an issue like this. But, why you don't put session information inside a JWT token? As I can see you are using token logic...

Comment: I suppose that can be a workaround and simply put into JWT token but then that somewhat defeats the purpose of sails...

Comment: My guess would be that you have a race condition where two cookies are being set for the same session.  Perhaps a loading spinner on the front end that's loading some webfont for its icon, or some other asset like an image that's being loaded dynamically when you click "submit" to log in.  If so, the solution is to make sure the asset is pre-loaded _before_ the user submits the login form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the connect-mongo adapter and found a similar problem. The reason is because when you use `req.session.user = user` the background code is saving your session to DB (in my case, Mongo, in yours Redis), and **before** it finishes, your code executes the `res.json` part.

To deal with the DB saving's asynchronous code, try to do something like this (haven't tested your code, but doing that to my case, solved the problem):

```
  AuthService.login(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(user => {

    // save user information in the session

    // this is on memory
    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.authenticated = true;

    // now the session is saved in DB
    req.session.save(function() {
      return res.json({
        user:user,
        token:token
      });
    }
  }).catch(err => {
  sails.log.error(err);
  res.json(403, {
    callstack: err.callstack,
    error: 'Authentication error',
    reason : err.reason
  });
});
```